# Jquery get input value from another text input value and set into hidden input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new at Jquery. My User Story: I have two input form tag. One is hidden and One is Text. I need to take value from input text and set that value into hidden input and then submit the form with both value. Is it possible to do in Jquery. Here is my example code:

```
if ($_POST) {
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $username = $_REQUEST['username'];

  echo "Email Value: " . $email ." And Username Value :" .$username;
}
```

```js
var lap = $("emailId").val();
var test = $("userId");
test.val(test);
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="emailId" name="email" type="text" value="">
  <input id="userId" name="username" type="hidden" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your jQuery id selectors are missing `#` prefix... `var test = $("#userId");` Should work fine with those fixed and `test.val(lap)`

Comment: I tried with id selector. Still no luck

Comment: As well as the `#` prefixes you need to use `test.val(lap)`. Also note that this logic will only execute when the page loads. If you want to update the value once one is entered you'll need to use an event handler. I'd suggest `input`.

Comment: Do you have an example event handler. I am still learning.Please help.

Comment: @mike1225 `$('input[type=submit]').on('click', yourFunction)`
This is event listener on input for click event

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this. I've provide a solution using jQuery as well as vanilla JavaScript.

**jQuery Version**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $email = $('#email')
  // Note that we are updating the hidden input value each time the
  // text input value changes. We could do this less frequently by
  // using the `input` or `change` event instead of the `keyup` event.
  $email.on('keyup', function(e){
    $('#userId').val($email.val())
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" />
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Vanilla JavaScript Version**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var txtEmail = document.querySelector('#email')
  var txtUserId = document.querySelector('#userId')
  // Note that we are updating the hidden input value each time the
  // text input value changes. We could do this less frequently by
  // using the `input` or `change` event instead of the `keyup` event.
  txtEmail.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    txtUserId.value = txtEmail.value
  })
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" />
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**A brief explanation of my method**

*Waiting for the HTML to load*

Whether you're using jQuery or not, depending on how your JavaScript and HTML code is stitched together, sometimes you're HTML elements are not available when your JavaScript code runs (for example, if your JavaScript code is included in the `<head>` tag, which I think has become pretty uncommon these days). For this reason, I've gotten into the habit of making sure the document is ready before I reference any HTML elements. Using jQuery, this is done with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // The code here (inside this function) will be executed after the HTML finishes loading.
})
```

With vanilla JavaScript, the code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  // The code here (inside this function) will be executed after the HTML finishes loading.
})
```

*Making Updates As Soon As Possible*

In addition, my code updates the hidden input value after the text input value has changed, rather than waiting for the form to be submitted. Either option may be perfectly acceptable for a given situation. I am in the habit of updating things like these as soon as possible; if in the future, I write some JavaScript code that is expecting the value of these to input controls to be equivalent, and that code runs before the form is submitted, I'll probably have a bug in my code. Hence, I find it safer to just update as soon as the change occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As per [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) You forgot to use `#` in your both selectors. You should use:

```
var lap = $("#emailId").val();
var test = $("#userId");
test.val(lap);
```

Comment: `test.val(test)` is incorrect and would make the value `"[object Object"]"`

Comment: Nice job referencing the documentation!

Comment: @Trevor Thank you Sir. I seen the value when I type in the input box in the console, how do I put this value in hidden input and submit the both value

Comment: @mike1225 Look at my answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53285919/269061). It sets the value of the hidden input automatically, so when you submit the form, the value will already be there.